# How preserve a value with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have this scenario :

I got an entity from a database

```
// Get the pending row where transactionId == paypal invoice
var receiptToComplete = (await _receiptService.SingleOrDefaultAsync(payPalCheckoutInfo.invoice, StatusConstant.PENDING));
```

Then I do a mapping like this:

```
var receiptId = receiptToComplete.Id; // Should put the Id in a temp variable to reassign after mapping, otherwise will be 0

receiptToComplete = Mapper.Map<WebServiceCheckout, Receipt>(payPalCheckoutInfo);

receiptToComplete.Id = receiptId; // Reassign id
```

How can I use AutoMapper **to not override** the Id field?

I tried

```
cfg.CreateMap<WebServiceCheckout, Receipt>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Id, x => x.Ignore())
```

But it doesn't work. I got the value 0.
My version of AutoMapper is 5.0.0

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an overload of Mapper.Map that doesn't require you to completely overwrite your destination.

```
Mapper.Map<WebServiceCheckout, Receipt>(payPalCheckoutInfo, receiptToComplete);
```

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you!!